# Adding repeating integers in a "for" loop a specified number of times

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to run a "for" loop that will start with the user defined value "d" (between 1 and 7) and add 1 continuously until it reaches the other user defined value "n". Here's the catch...I need it to repeat the count back to "1" once the value "7" is reached without it being stuck in an infinite loop.

For example, my program prompts a user to input 2 numbers and it stores them as "d" and "n" respectively. The first number can be "1-7" and the second number can be anything. So, if the user inputs "5" and "10" I need my loop to start counting at "6" and count up "10" times, starting back over at "1" once the value has reached "7". It should look like this...
"6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1".

Right now I have it looking like this...
"6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15"

This is my current code and output with "5 = d" and "10 = n"

**Code**

```
public void incrementDay3()
{ 
  int i;

  for(i = (d + 1);i <= (d + n);i++)
  {
     System.out.print(i);
  }
}
```

**Output**

"6789101112131415"

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use ``String#join`` after storing up the sequence elements in e.g. an ``ArrayList``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (**modulo operator**) :

```
public void incrementDay3()
{ 
    int i;
    for(i = d ; i < (d + n) ; i++)
    {
        System.out.print((i % 7) + 1);
    }
}
```

For more information about what a modulo is, you can check this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: This is actually quite a clean way to solve this. +1 for modulo - but change `<=` to `<` or else it counts one too far

Comment: That almost worked for the result, except it added an 11th integer "2" at the end. Now that I see the result I also need to code it so it does not print out the integers in sequence, but still counts in that fashion. I added in the "System.out.print" just so I could see how it was counting.  Also, I need to  reassign the final integer back to "d". How would I go about doing that?

Comment: The 11th integer has been corrected after @MuratK. pointed it.
For what you want, replace the "System.out.print" by "int value = (i % 7) + 1;" and you can work with it. And if you declare that value outside the for loop, you'll be able to get it at the end.

Comment: @wd719 Open a new thread for a new question. This answer solves your current problem.

Comment: Thanks @VLef and Murat K.! I will post a new thread with the rest of my problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void incrementDay3()
{
    int i;
    int d = 5, n = 10;

    int result;
    result = d + 1;

    for(i = result;i <= (d + n);i++)
    {
        result++;
        if(result > 7)
            result = 1;
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this variant easier to read. In particular, the "simple for loop that just counts to `n`" is instantly recognizable, and easier to parse than the loop condition in the current best answer.

```
public static void incrementMod7(int d, int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        d = (d%7) + 1;
        System.err.print(d + " ");        
    }
}
```

Comment: Straightforward `for` loop conditions should count for something.

Comment: @MuratK. less is more: now with no pesky `if`

Answer (score 0):

```
int d=5;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  d =(d==7)?1:d+1;
  System.out.println(d);
}
```

easy.